# git , как удалить commit по его ID

Tags: git

я пытаюсь удалить commit по его ID, но у меня не получается

```
commit bea406bec9d4ce5837028c5eacab762b360193a0 (HEAD -> dev_denis_ua)
Author: login <myemail@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue May 12 23:25:28 2020 +0300

    git ignore for dev_denis branch
```

я пытаюсь использовать команды

`git reset --hard bea406bec9d4ce5837028c5eacab762b360193a0`

`git reset --soft bea406bec9d4ce5837028c5eacab762b360193a0`

Но ничего не срабатывает

Как правильно удалить commit?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "удалить коммит"? И что именно означает "не  срабатывает "?

Comment: удалить его локально и с бренчи

Comment: reset ничего не удаляет (т.е. удаляет,  но не коммиты)

Comment: так подскажите как удалить, в этом же и вопрос

Comment: rebase может быть поможет

Comment: rebase это слить коммиты, а мне нужно удалить

Comment: Вы в `git reset` указываете ID того коммита, который хотите откатить? Нужно указать предыдущий перед ним, `reset` откатывает ДО указанного коммита

Comment: если это последний коммит (или следующие за ним тоже не нужны), используйте reset, только надо указать на предыдущий коммит — либо хёш предыдущего коммита, либо хэш данного, но с `^`: `bea406bec^`. если этот коммит не последний (и следующие за ним надо сохранить), воспользуйтесь rebase.